# Can I Find X-01 Parts in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

**I've found and looted most of the power armor frames in the Wasteland. Where can I find X-01 armor pieces?**

This game is weird, to me, in that they slap you with the level dependent bit, AND random number generator, and I had the locations of the frames too early. Some of them, like 35 Court, or whatever, are just as hard, regardless of my level, but the prize is less.

I found a suit with X-01 parts, in the Glowing Sea, but it only had three parts. The only people I've fought wearing PA are Raiders, who have junk suits, and if I did fight BoS (I'm allied with them, this playthrough), I expect they all have T-60.

Will the Atom Cats ever sell X-01? Are there any other places to just find some parts lying around, even without the frame? Did I shoot myself in the foot, and am SOL, due to my exploring?

I found one by Jamaica Plains, but it was still T-60, at level 32; it might've level-locked from when I first went to Jamaica Plains, I don't know. I really wish some loot was "we made this hard, but if you can get it...", rather than "this will be post-game armor, almost no matter what? I spent a lot of time looking for the "surefire" locations for X-01 armors, and wasn't aware that they were level-dependent, so I think I've found most of them (11 frames, never bought or stole one), and this might mean I can't get the whole suit, as I was too quick to get them.

Can anyone assist?

Comment: Less can be more when it comes to questions.  Your question seems to boil down to, "I've found and looted most of the power armor frames in the Wasteland.  Where can I find X-01 armor pieces?"

Comment: You can find them at military checkpoints, the buildings that have a star with a circle around it as an icon on the map. There is some T-45/51/60s in them, but the best spot is the National Guard Training Yard Armory. Be careful though, once you leave the armory with the suit, a sentry bot will be hostile!

Answer (score 10):

The south Boston military checkpoint has a full set of leveled power armor.  If your level is high enough(above 26) it'll be x-01.

Answer (score 5):

From http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/X-01_power_armor#Locations :

- A helmet can be found at Proctor Teagan's shop on The Prydwen behind a door locked with a Master level terminal, and can be stolen.
- If the player character is a high enough level when starting the Brotherhood of Steel quest "Blind Betrayal", a full set of X-01 missing the helmet can be seen being worn by Paladin Danse after completing the quest.

Bought from:

- Various pieces can be purchased from Rowdy at Atom Cats garage, depending on player character's level. Rowdy's shop refreshes at the same time as shops in the settlements.

X-01 armor appears to start spawning at level 26.

Comment: I thought it was level 28 - http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=564707901

Comment: BTW you should mark your answer in spoilers

Answer (score 4):

There's a location called the Abandoned Shack in the Glowing Sea that has a few armor pieces on a frame.

The shack is actually an entrance to a military bunker. Fight your way down through the complex (or jump down) and there's a frame with about three pieces of power armor on a frame tucked in the corner. To get out of the building, you can either climb up again or reboot the maintenance mainframe from a terminal in the corner (which activates the elevator).

Comment: Don't do this. Just provide the details.

Comment: Fixed. Wasn't sure about the spoiler policy here.

Comment: You can use the [spoiler] tag I think.

Answer (score 4):

I found my set on top of a building called Court 35, near the Custom House Tower.  Go inside, fight your way to the top of the building.  Up top, there are a few assaultrons and a sentry bot.  Kill them, and there's a full set of X-01 just waiting for you in the lockup.  Grab it and jump off the building.  (Not sure what level I was when I got this, but I think it was below level 30).

Comment: I think I only encountered one Assaultron (left) and Sentry Bot. Note: from where they spawn there are buttons you need to press in order to access the armor.

Comment: Note that the armor *might* look like T-60 (etc ) until you enter the frame. It will still list it as X-01 when you check the frame inverntory

Answer (score 1):

(spoilers) road between nordhagen beach and fort strong has a checkpoint for entry to fort strong. X-01 set missing legs there. Court 35 has the only full set I know of. Court 35 can be really easy if you have some pulse mines in your inventory just put them in front of the doors the robots come out of. I believe the X-01 will not spawn in any of the points listed in this thread unless you are at least lev 26-28. I know the armor at ft strong checkpoint was not x-01 when my first character went there way before the BOS mission but it was when my second character went there after the BOS mission. I think the games is designed to encourage mix and match. There is one piece of raider armor that is not junk called Tessa's Fist. Tessa's Fist has the legendary star and makes your armor 4 times more durable. Handy if your tired of constantly repairing you companions power armor. I prefer Danse as a companion mainly because you don't have to constantly fix his armor

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm out of luck. I've managed to cobble together most of a suit of the X-01 armor, but I hit most of the "listed locations" for it on the Internet way too early, before those same sources mentioned the level-dependent bit. Due to no one using X-01 armor, I don't think I' find that last piece, as I rarely find armor in pieces, like loot in chests; only when I find a suit, or kill a Raider leader. I've heard that the Atom Cats can sell it, but I'm lvl 49, and I've been there lots; Rowdy has never had a piece of X-01 for sale. Oh well, one different arm won't kill me, right? ;)